# Jenkins build number: accessing from called Java program

Tags: java, jenkins, build-numbers

How can I access the Jenkins build number and job path from the called Java program into this program?

Background: during the Java program runs, I want to create a dynamic link with this program (`pathtothecurrentbuild/log`) to the log file of the current run as an information for the admins in case of trouble.

Comment: do you get the answer of your questions. Can you please tell me how u able to resolve this ?

Comment: can you reply to my question?

Answer (score 3):

Already the jenkins job are predefined with set of some environment variables like BUILD_NUMBER,JOB_NAME etc. These list of variables with name and description will be available in the url - http:// Your Jenkin URL/**env-vars.html** (Ex:http://cptest-Jenkins/env-vars.html)

These list of environment variables can be easily accessed using below code.

```
System.out.println("Build Number:"+System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER")); //BUILD_NUMBER - name of the environment variable
```

This will print the current build number. Same way you can access other variables also.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your java program is called but they should be set and environment-variables in the job so you should be able to access them from java or send them as parameters to the java program.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

Comment: I thought about again and "print" out the whole environment of a running job. I found some env vars, that helps and so I solved this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can have following line in your application.properties.
service.version=${BUILD_NUMBER}

and then from in your java code, you can use this service.version.